# Is it possible to insert xml as a string to varbinary and it will be similiar to be inserted as a blob?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Is it possible to insert xml as a string to varbinary and it will be similiar to be inserted as a blob? For example When i insert xml as a blob

```
declare @i int = 1
declare @file varchar(2000) = concat('K:\test\file',@i,'.xml');
declare @blob varbinary(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat(N'select @blob = BulkColumn FROM 
OPENROWSET(BULK ''',@file,''', SINGLE_BLOB) myfile')

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@blob varbinary(max) output', @blob = @blob 
output
select @blob 

insert tab1 values (@blob)
```

File inserted as a blob look like this[image]

When i insert the same xml but as a string

```
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES ( Convert (varbinary(MAX), N'
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>'  ))
```

It looks completaly different

[image]

@Jacob

[image]

@Siyual

[image]

Comment: Why not just use the xml data type instead? Doesn't answer your question about why your blob appears to be different than the varbinary data.

Comment: Does your file also have a linebreak at the beginning of it, before the `<note>`?

Comment: @Jacob it has to varbinary data type but I have tried your idea to save as xml and then convert it as a varbinary but the output is different than the those 2 i mentioned before.

Comment: @Siyual Deleting the linebreak does not help aswell.

Answer (score 0):

It is a **very bad idea** to store a file as `VARBINARY` just as you read it from disk.

Some background

```
DECLARE @YourThirdVarbinary VARBINARY(MAX)=0xfffe3c006e006f00740065003e003c0074006f003e00;
SELECT CAST(@YourThirdVarbinary AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

The leading `FFFE` points to an *UTF-16 little endian* encoded file with a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

The following 3C00 6E00 6F00 ... shows clearly, that you are reading *2-byte encoded* characters.

SQL-Server uses `UCS-2` internally and is not capeable to read each and any `UTF-16` encoding natively. I assume, that you are living in a country, where you are dealing with many characters, which are not *plain latin*...

But the first example you provide is a *single-byte* encoded string:

```
DECLARE @YourFirstVarbinary VARBINARY(MAX)=0x3c6e6f74653E0D0A3c746f3e546f76653c2f746f3e;
SELECT CAST(@YourFirstVarbinary AS VARCHAR(MAX));
```

The missing `00` between your code points shows clearly, that this is *1-byte-storage* without a BOM, probably some kind of `UTF-8`!

`UTF-8` stores plain latin with one single byte, but special characters will take more bytes, up to 4 bytes for one single letter.

SQL-Server will treat a *1-byte* encoded string as `VARCHAR`, which is *extended ascii*, relying on a `COLLATION` (including a `code page`) (*multi-byte-codes* must lead to errors!)

You will find the same codepoints forming the word `<note>`:

```
DECLARE @PureCodePoints VARBINARY(MAX)=0x3c6e6f74653E;
SELECT CAST(@PureCodePoints AS VARCHAR(MAX));
```

And as *2-byte* code (see the `N`VARCHAR):

```
DECLARE @PureCodePointsWide VARBINARY(MAX)=0x3c006e006f00740065003E00;
SELECT CAST(@PureCodePointsWide AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

### Clear advise

- Store your XML in a natively typed column! Advantage: XML is not stored as the text you see, but as a *hierachy tree*. This is **much faster**! With your approach you'd have to cast the `VARBINARY` to a string and parse this over and over again...
- Never store data as `VARBINARY`, if you cannot ensure, that you know the encoding in any case and that SQL-Server will be able to deal with this format.

Answer (score 0):

The way you store your XML depends on what you're going to do with this data.

- if your goal is just to store and access the file, regardless of whether it is indeed an XML or not, [varbinary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [FILESTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) is absolutely fine.
- if you know it is a text file (including XML) but don't require any XML-specific operations with it, you'd be okay with [varchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [nvarchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
- if you're going to do any kind of XML manipulations, [xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would be the logical choice.

From my experience, there are some caveats in the latter:

- An XML might be signed and, if you should be careful not to break it. In this case, you should consider storing the XML as a binary, but add an extra XML column.
- If you have an XML that specifies an encoding that is not compatible with the one the application provides, you might have an error such as:

  > XML parsing: line 1, character 45, unable to switch the encoding

  The following examples illustrate this scenario:

```sql
SELECT CAST(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><xml></xml>' AS xml)
SELECT CAST(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xml></xml>' AS xml)
SELECT CAST('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><xml></xml>' AS xml)
```

while these are fine:

```sql
SELECT CAST(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><xml></xml>' AS xml)
SELECT CAST('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xml></xml>' AS xml)
SELECT CAST('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><xml></xml>' AS xml)
SELECT CAST(N'<xml></xml>' AS xml)
SELECT CAST('<xml></xml>' AS xml)
```